# Read text file outside my JSP content directory

Tags: jsp, readline

I want to read a Text file from C:/Users/Owner/Documents/number.txt

here's my code for read.jsp

```
 <% String filePath = request.getParameter("inputFileElement"); %>  
 <html>  
 <head>  
  <title>display</title>  
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
 <%@page import="java.io.*" %>  

 </head>  
  <body>  
  <%  
   String fileName = filePath;  
   BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));  
   String fileData = "";  

   while((fileData = is.readLine()) != null)  
  {  
   out.println(fileData);  
 }  
  %>  
  </body>  
  </html>
```

I always got this error HTTP Status 404 - number.txt (No such file or directory)

What is my wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly get a file from local system, there is some security problem. [This link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider adding the external file into the project directory:

**public**

> Even a simple hyperlink can point to this file

YourWebApp > web > number.txt

**restricted**

> Here you need to put some efforts to show the file contents

YourWebApp > web > WEB-INF > number.txt